# jquery tablesorter - on ajax update I'm losing sorting functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I've seen a few questions like this but as far as I can see I am doing everything correctly, I am a bit stumped as to why this isn't working.

Here is my ajax call which is inside a click function. `#result_area` is the tbody of the table and as you can see I am replacing the content. The content is loading fine but i lose table sorting functionality. Strange thing is, I'm sure this used to work so i am a bit perplexed as to what has changed. I have checked in firebug and the trigger update is definitely being called.

**Update**

I am getting the following error when $("#result_table").trigger("update"); is called:

```
Error: TypeError: parsers[i] is undefined
Source File: http://swishprint.dev/assets/js/common/jquery.tablesorter.js
Line: 483
```

Line 483 refers to the following:

```
function getCachedSortType(parsers,i) {
return parsers[i].type;
};
```

**table initialisation function (called in doc ready):**

```
    function table_init() {
        $('#result_table').tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        widgetZebra: {
            css: ["dark", "darker"]
        },
        headers: {
            0: {
            sorter: false
            },
            5: {
            sorter: false
            },
            7: {
            sorter: false
            },
            8: {
            sorter: false
            }
          }
       });
}
```

**click function:**

```
    function leftsort_click(event) { //main sort click (left menu)

    //build url and other unrelated stuff
            var page = window.name,
            page_index, api = $('#right_pane').jScrollPane({
                showArrows: true,
                maintainPosition: false
            }).data('jsp');   
            if (!$(this).hasClass('sort_cat')) {        
            $('ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var sid = $(this).attr('id');
            var title = $(this).html();
            var loadUrlx = page;
            if ((sid != '') && (sid != 'undefined')) {
                loadUrlx += '/' + sid;
            }
            var loadUrlStub = loadUrlx;
            if ($('.rpp_btn.active').length >= 1) {
                var res_per_page = $.trim($('.rpp_btn.active').html());
                page_index = $.trim($('.res_page_select.active a').html());
                if (($('.rpp_btn.active').hasClass('just_clicked')) || (!$('.res_page_select').hasClass('just_clicked'))) {
                page_index = '1';
                }
                if ((page_index != 1) || (res_per_page != 25)) {
                loadUrlx += '/' + page_index + '/' + res_per_page;
                }
                $('.rpp_btn, .res_page_select').removeClass('just_clicked');
            }       
            loadUrlx = b_url + loadUrlx;
            if (History.enabled) {
                History.pushState(null, null, loadUrlx);
                //var hash=History.getHash(), rootUrl = History.getRootUrl(), State = History.getState(), url = State.url, relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');
            }
//Ajax call            
              $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    url: loadUrlx,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#result_area").html(result);
                        if ((page != 'home') && (page != 'guides')) {
                            var count_ele = $('.hidden_rescount').length;

                            //get td width and set width of table headers
                            api.reinitialise();
                            tsizer();
                            $("#result_table").trigger("update");
                        }
                    }
            });
        }
```

**call for click function (in doc ready):**

```
$('#mainc').on("click", "ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li", function(event) {
    leftsort_click.call(this);
    });
    }
```

My HTML

```
<table width="100%" class="result_table tablesorter scrollableFixedHeaderTable" id="result_table" style="">
    <thead id="t_header">
        <tr>
            <th class="border_apps th_first th_img no-sort" id="th_img">IMG</th>
            <th class="border_apps th_name header headerSortUp" id="th_name">NAME</th>
            <th class="border_apps th_cat header" id="th_cat">CAT</th>
            <th class="border_apps th_urate header" id="th_urate">RATING <small>(USER)</small></th>
            <th class="border_apps th_orate header" id="th_orate">RATING <small>(ODDBALL)</small></th>
            <th class="border_apps th_info no-sort" id="th_info">INFO</th>
            <th class="border_apps th_alert header" id="th_alert">W</th>            <th class="border_apps th_edit no-sort" id="th_edit">EDIT</th>            <th class="border_apps th_last th_link no-sort" id="th_link">LINK</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="result_area">
//results here

</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code where tablesorter is initialized?

Comment: i have included it now, see the table_init function at the top, I call this in document ready as part of a larger page_init function.... I have tried calling this function instead of update after the ajax call aswell but it doesn't work

Comment: All the extra coding is confusing the issue for me. How is the ajax called? Are you sure the ajax is successful?

Comment: sorry, it started simpler and I have been asked to include more and more, I have tried to clean it up a bit. its in the click function, at the bottom - I've added a comment (probably should do more of that)

Comment: Ajax function is successful, data is loaded correctly and I can follow script flow through firebug and see success function being run

Comment: Are you sure the update is called? I'm hoping the page it loads isn't named "home" or "guides" `(page != 'home') && (page != 'guides')`

Comment: Is it being called? Well its certainly not doing anythingif it is but I can put a breakpoint at the line $("#result_table").trigger("update"); and it hits it. No, its not guide or home page - no tables on those pages hence the exception. I think I would have to go hide in a corner if I'd done that. lol

Comment: Hmm, well I'm out of ideas then LOL. I might suggest you try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Mottie, I may try that next but suspect I'll get the same result, since you obviously know this plugin pretty well could you take another look and see the error message I have just realised I'm getting. At the top of my question under update

Comment: I seem to remember the original tablesorter not parsing the header if the tbody was empty... I fixed that in my fork. Otherwise, make sure you're not clearing out the thead rows (which it doesn't look like you're doing) in the update.

Comment: thanks mottie, theads are fine, I'll try your fork - will I have to do anything other than switch the script (any access method changes)?

Comment: The only thing you'll need to do is pick a theme (set the `theme` option). The "default" theme is the default option and the file name changed to `theme.default.css` - but it's not the "blue" one ;)... otherwise it should work the same.

Comment: @Mottie, Thanks for all your help... turned out to be a problem with sorting on a hidden table row I was adding, found the debug option in your docs which pointed me to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to account for dynamically loaded information (via Ajax) with jQuery's on() method, specifically event delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on/

When you originally load the page all of your jQuery code is run against elements existing in the page at that time. jQuery / JavaScript is not aware of any changes to the DOM made by dynamically loaded content after that. Using the delegation method of on() you can bind to a container that exists on the page at the time that it loads. When dynamic content is added to the container any event triggered in the container bubbles up to the existing element and is then acted on properly.

For example you could do something like this -

```
$('#result_area').on('event', 'element_causing_event', function() {...
```

In this case the element_causing_event will cause the event to bubble up to #result_area where it can then be handled.

After checking the docs (http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html) it seems that you can update the table to let the plugin know that data has been added -

```
$('#result_table').trigger('update');
```

This should allow normal sorting. Try calling it in the success callback of your AJAX request.

Comment: I am using .on(click) to trigger this function, do I need to do something else?

Comment: Instead of using inline events you should use jQuery's event handlers. As an added bonus it'll be cleaner. @Florian Margaine I had hit enter too quickly and it is hard to provide too much of an example because we need to see the markup that results after the AJAX call is made.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried to isolate what I thought was the problem code, I am still unclear, I will update my question...

Comment: Can you post the resulting markup after the AJAX call? Maybe create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I appreciate your time, I have posted the full js and html structure, the markup after the ajax call is as expected, series of tr elements inside tbody. I dont know how to turn it into a js fiddle as I'm on a dev server, so I dont know where i would pull the ajax content from.

Comment: You could just make it static for our purposes.

Comment: I just had a go but I'm struggling to even get tablesorter to work in jsfiddle, and i've had to change the markup and js so much I very much doubt it will replicate the problem

Comment: i have included it now, see the table_init function at the top, I call this in document ready as part of a larger page_init function.... I have tried calling this function instead of update after the ajax call aswell but it doesn't work

Comment: I have added to my answer above based on the docs for tablesorter

Comment: I saw, it's in the success call of my ajax function and I've checked if firebug that it is being called - this is what I'm saying it's frying my brain.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, partly because its the only one I got. But also because the issue turned out to be an issue with the content I was loading (something Jay suggested) - I had a hidden row containing data which couldnt be sorted. This was throwing the sorting script.